# Facebook FQL query to get all users online

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I keep record of all users of my app in local, MySQL database. I have all the relevant information required to get user online presence status [`UID, access_token` and granted `extended permission`].

**How do I get online presence status of all users?**

The approach I am using at the moment, is to query each user separately:

```
$facebook->api(array
(
    'access_token'  => 'x',
    'method'        => 'fql.query',
    'query'     => "SELECT uid, name, first_name, last_name, online_presence FROM user WHERE uid = x"
));
```

But this is time taking procedure with 150 users. I am not even talking about 400+ or 1000+.

p.s. multiquery didn't work for me, because asking user presence requires to provide the `access_token`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
SELECT name, uid, online_presence FROM user WHERE uid=me()
```

Answer (score 0):

For all online

```
SELECT name,uid FROM user WHERE
  online_presence IN ('active', 'idle')
```

With friend

```
SELECT name,uid FROM user WHERE
  online_presence IN ('active', 'idle')
  AND uid IN (
    SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $user_id
  )
```

Comment: this doesn't work: Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from

Comment: i'm trying to find a valid solution too.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an option and in terms of why you would need this data, it is not readily apparent as to the purpose of it.  Maybe if you could provide more information, a different solution would be available.

Another viable option is to rely on the Chat API. This will tell you all the users that are set to online status in Facebook Chat.  This wouldn't be too reliable as this includes users accessing solely the Facebook Chat(desktop/mobile software) as opposed to the actual website users.