# Facebook Graph API, how to get facebook online friends list?

Tags: android, facebook, status

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook online friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666153/facebook-online-friend)

I am using the Facebook Graph API and I was wondering if there was anyway to get a list of all the users and their current online-status (i.e Online or Offline) in one call?

Now i'm able to get list of users from Hash book Example, in that return JSONArray don't have any object related to this online-status.

**EDIT**: now i'm using this query for getting friends list `query = "select name, current_location, uid, pic_square from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) order by name";` but i want only online friends list.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi raja,can u help me how to get facebook online friendslis?

Comment: @sandeep look at the answer and duplicate link . it's working for me.

Comment: Hi raja, can u say where to use that query.iam new to this.

Comment: like fb.query() with quesry string, search for Facebook graph api you will get some code .

Comment: Hi,iam getting null response

Comment: String fqlQuery = "SELECT name,uid FROM user WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle') AND uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";  This is the query iam using.And i need online friends list..I have to add any permissions..Thanks in Advance

Comment: That's fine. it will work.

Comment: Hi raja,i have issue with online friends list.The issue is when i login with developer account(means with which i created facebook app id),then iam getting all online friends of that account,but when i logged with different account then it showing only developer acc is in online(if he was in online)and for other user its showing offline..please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/5669441/1458047. When you gain these rights, you should be able to access the status over fql.

along with this it requires a FQL query--- `SELECT name,uid FROM user WHERE
  online_presence IN ('active', 'idle')
  AND uid IN (
    SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())`

Comment: This is no longer valid, is there a way to get online users with new API?