# get online friends C# facebook.dll

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-fql

I want to get list of online friends and I have 
`An unhandled exception of type 'Facebook.FacebookApiException' occurred in Facebook.dll
Additional information: (104) Requires valid signature`

What wrong in my code? Thx!

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("vasya.pupkin");
var uId = myInfo.id;

dynamic friends = fb.Query("SELECT uid FROM user WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle')           AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = "+uId+")");

//WriteLine(friends.Count);
```

and I dont understand what meaning of `uid`, `uid2`, `uid1` - it must be write as it, or i must to write there some id's (as i write +uId+ in the end of line?).

Answer (score 1):

Well, Facebook requires an authentication token.  That variable is usually assigned by those Key and Secret request.  Without the proper authentication or application being accepted by the Facebook user it won't work.

The reason I mention that *Token* is because the UID is usually the numbers after a profile or application identifier like so:

[image: UID Example]

I'm not sure what step you're on but:
[image: Facebook Key and Secret]

You have to create an application that utilizes the Application ID, and Application Secret.  Without that token, you can't actually access Facebook.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="EnableSqlDependency" value="true" />
    <add key="ApplicationId" value="<YOUR APP ID GOES HERE>" />
    <add key="ApplicationUrl" value="" />
    <add key="ApiKey" value="" />
    <add key="ApplicationSecret" value="<YOUR APP SECRET GOES HERE>" />
    <add key="ExtendedPermissions" value="offline_access" />
  </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Will need to go in your `app.config`.

Now inside of Facebook:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(this.AccessToken);
dynamic result = fb.Post("me/feed", new { message = 
     "My second wall post using Facebook C# SDK" });
```

You'll have access.

The UID is basically the Application ID or User ID your trying to identify.  That is why you keep receiving that error.  You don't have a valid session to physically access it.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: thank you Greg, but I create application as u say, and i can to post some text on wall..but to get list of ONLINE friends i can't..I also add(User & Friend Permissions:
user_about_me user_activities friends_about_me friends_activities
AND
Extended Permissions:user_online_presence friends_online_presence read_friendlists).

Comment: @user2148334 I did a very generic tutorial, if you Google it they will go into more detail. I was simply identifying your problem for you with the reason it is failing.

Comment: can u give me link to your generic tutorial, or how i can find it?

Comment: Just type c# linked to Facebook

Answer (score 0):

After looking around on the FQL documentation and further searching StackOverflow, I suggest you take a look at: [How to get list of online friends using FQL with facebook API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795934/how-to-get-list-of-online-friends-using-fql-with-facebook-api)

You may also need to take a look here: [Facebook online friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666153/facebook-online-friend)

I suggest you spend a little more time looking around the StackOverflow site next time as it took 10 seconds and a google query of "facebook api get online friends" to find the answers I have provided.