# Why do some Facebook friends appear offline to third-party chat clients even though they are online?

Tags: facebook

I've developed an app using the Facebook Chat XMPP gateway, and users of this app report that some of their friends appear offline in this app, even though those same friends appear online in the official Facebook web and mobile clients. Why is this? Are there any relevant privacy settings that these friends may have enabled? Note that my app does have the `user_online_presence` and `friends_online_presence` permissions.

Comment: Similar to this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666153/facebook-online-friend   Do you have the user_status permission?